# Change value of textbox based on value of select list

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have been searching for a way to do this for over 2 hours and still have not found a solution:(. I am using a Razor component and I want to display details for the registration of a `Student`. So if a `Month` is picked, a text box with their Semester should show. An example would be if the month 1(January) is pick from the list, the semester text box should show 1(the number of the semester).

Student model:

```
public partial class StudentDetails
{
    public int StudentNumber{ get; set; }
    public int StudentAge{ get; set; }
    public int Month{ get; set; }
    public int Semester{ get; set; }
    public string FName { get; set; }
}
```

Registration Model:

```
public partial class Reg
{
    public int Month{ get; set; }
    public int Semester{get; set;  }
}
```

Select box:

```
<MudSelect  @bind-Value="student.Month" For="@(()=>Student.Month)" T="int"  Label="Student Joining Month" AnchorOrigin="Origin.BottomCenter" Required="true">
    @foreach (var item in num)
    {
        <MudSelectItem T="int" Value="@item.Month">@item.Month</MudSelectItem>
    }  
</MudSelect>
```

Comment: Maybe tell us what you have tried so far and where exactly you are stuck. Did you manage to show the select box (without the text box for now)?

Comment: @DimitrisMaragkos, sorry about that, I have updated the question to include the select box, it does let me select a student number and store into the db

Comment: How is `Reg` model linked to the `StudentDetails`? `Reg` class should have e.g. a `StudentId` property that links the specific registration to a specific student (one-to-one relationship).

Comment: It's not enough to have the month. There could be thousands of registrations on that month. How do I know which is the registration of the specific student that is selected?

Comment: @DimitrisMaragkos, no no, So in the Student form, the user will fill in the number, age and name, then there is a select list for Month for when they will be joining. That select list is linked to the Reg table which pulls the months of the year into. Once the Month of the year is chosen, I would want the semester that corresponds to the month(in the Reg table) to be populated in the text field below the select list

Comment: So the `StudentDetails` class is actually irrelevant for this?

Comment: @DimitrisMaragkos, I am being a complete noob today, I really am sorry... I have updated the question again to include the semester field, I notice that it is needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
<MudSelect Value="@student.Month" ValueChanged="@OnMonthChanged" T="int" Label="Month" AnchorOrigin="Origin.BottomCenter" Required="true">
    @foreach (var registration in registrations)
    {
        <MudSelectItem T="int" Value="@registration.Month">@registration.Month</MudSelectItem>
    }  
</MudSelect>

@* should be readonly *@
<MudTextField @bind-Value="@student.Semester" Label="Semester" ReadOnly="true" Variant="Variant.Text" />
    
@code {
    private List<Reg> registrations;
    private StudentDetails student = new();

    private void OnMonthChanged(int selectedMonth)
    {
        student.Month = selectedMonth;
        
        // get the registration based on the selected month
        var registration = registrations.Single(r => r.Month == selectedMonth);
        
        // set the semester of student details
        student.Semester = registration.Semester;
    }
}
```

Comment: This stores the Semester in the db only though, doesn't it? 
the drop down should store the month and the test field should store the semester :(

Comment: Ok check answer now.

Comment: It works!! How did you figure that out?